# using group by in my query

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, group-by

I have the following query that adds each record to a list that is displayed in as dataTable on a Visualforce page.

```
    for (MyObject__c obj : [SELECT Date__c, Stage__c, Members__c, Type__c, Company__c, Primary_Company__r.Name, Secondary_Company__r.Name, Alternate_Company__r.Name, Status__c FROM MyObject__c WHERE Status__c = 'Active' ORDER BY Date__c ASC, Type__c DESC, Primary_Company__r.Name DESC, Secondary_Company__r.Name DESC]){
        if ((obj.Stage__c == 'Received' || obj.Stage__c == 'In Progress' || obj.Stage__c == 'Call' || obj.Stage__c == 'Queue') && (obj.Members__c != null ? !obj.Members__c.contains('TBA') : true)){
            recordsToReturn.add(obj);
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to group the resultset by Primary_Company__r.Name?  So, when the list is displayed on the page, all records where the Primary_Company__r.Name are the same will be grouped together on the page.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably (there are some restrictions on referencing on more complication forms) make use of a [relationship query](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm) where you query the parent object (you don't give its name so I'm guessing its something like Company__c) and at the same time bring back all the child objects across one of the relationships:

```
companies = [
        select Name, (
                SELECT Date__c, Stage__c, Members__c, Type__c, Company__c, Status__c,
                        Secondary_Company__r.Name, Alternate_Company__r.Name
                FROM PrimaryMyObjects__r
                WHERE Status__c = 'Active'
                ORDER BY Date__c ASC, Type__c DESC, Secondary_Company__r.Name DESC
                )
        FROM Company__c
        WHERE ID IN (
                SELECT Primary_Company__c
                FROM MyObject__c
                WHERE Status__c = 'Active'
                )
        ORDER BY Name DESC
];
```

This automatically generates the list of child objects for each parent object (and so groups the child objects). You will need to check the relationship name (I'm guessing PrimaryMyObjects__r). A good thing about using queries here is that the normal "order by" and "where" mechanisms are available for both the parent and child records.

You can then present the data in Visualforce using e.g.:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!companies}" var="company">
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!company.PrimaryMyObjects__r}" var="myObject">
        ...
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:repeat>
```

An alternative approach is to do the grouping in controller code:

```
names = new List<String>();
myObjectsByCompanyName = new Map<String, List<MyObject__c>>();
for (MyObject__c obj : [...]) {
    if (...) {
        String name = obj.Primary_Company__r.Name;
        names.add(name);
        List<MyObject__c> l = myObjectsByCompanyName.get(name);
        if (l == null) {
            myObjectsByCompanyName.put(name, l);
        }
        l.add(object)
    }
}
names.sort();
```

You can then present the data in Visualforce using e.g.:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!names}" var="name">
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!myObjectsByCompanyName[name]}" var="myObject">
        ...
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:repeat>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a map

```
Map<String,MyObject__c[]>
```

Populate the Map by the Primary_Company__r.Name as the key

The in you VF page use `Apex:Repeat` to cycle through

```
<apex:repeat value="{!THEMAP}" var="key">
    <apex:repeat value="{!THEMAP[key]}" var="rec">
        {!key} - {!rec} //Output how you need to
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:repeat>
```